# Sidekiq remove schedule documentation

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

There are 2 methods in the documentation of gem 'sidekiq-scheduler' to work with dynamic schedule (https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler#dynamic-schedule):

```
Sidekiq.set_schedule('heartbeat', { 'every' => ['1m'], 'class' => 'HeartbeatWorker' })
Sidekiq.get_schedule
```

But I can't find any method to remove the schedule that was already set before.

**Is there a way to find documentation with a full list of methods of the Sidekiq (with method description)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `remove_schedule(name)` to remove a schedule that has been set already. You can find more information, including the available methods in the RubyDocs [v2.0.20](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sidekiq-scheduler/2.0.20/SidekiqScheduler/Schedule#set_schedule-instance_method) or [v3.0.0](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sidekiq-scheduler/3.0.0/SidekiqScheduler/Schedule).